# How to route http request when under VPN

Tags: iis, routes, vpn

I have a laptop running Windows 8.1.
I have IIS up and running. I have Web Services there.
To use my company's resources, I should connect to it's VPN. I need this VPN access, so my Web Services can connect to database using Windows Authentication.  However, VPN was used (even if connected) only for those resources. So, when I was browsing stuff in Internet, sites saw my real ISP's IP and not VPN's.

Starting from today this was changed. Now, if I'm under VPN, I have company's IP and I can't access my laptop from anywhere. Previously, I could access it using my real IP.
I asked admin, what happed. The answer -

> Split tunneling when on VPN has been disabled in response to US
>   Federal Government requirements.

So, everything is working, except access from outside to my local IIS.
Is there any way, I can put some local (on my laptop maybe) routing, so external can access my laptop?

Comment: Please, don't throw stones on me, I'm not admin. I might miss some details or use wrong word for smth. Just ask me, I'll try to explain, if I'm able :-)

Comment: Didn't you find it ridiculous to have such a setup that your IIS site might expose confidential info of your company to the outside world? None of IT security best practice allows such.

Comment: @LexLi, how can you access you Web Service in another way, rather then open it for the World? If your are talking about my laptop and VPN - it's for development purposes. I host WS only. And db don't have any real data. I don't see any problem with security here.

Comment: IIS is more fragile than you thought where without proper configuration a hacker can easily exploit it and use it to gain further permissions and access to the resources this machine connects to. If you hadn't read about that somewhere you are warned now. I could hardly believe your company allows such a setup, but you can ignore what I said in the way you like. My firm of course has web services opened to the outside, but they are protected by a series of necessary components and running in isolated production environment and I would not call my personal laptop such an environment at all.